# How do we handle xml and json configuration with the same strongly-typed class in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, .net-standard

I have been looking for an answer on how to handle both .xml and .json config based configuration with same strongly-typed class in a .NET Standard 2.0 class library but without luck.
So my questions are. Is this even possible, do I have to have another approach on this?
Below summarize what I've tried.

So my situation is that I want to be able to use the same strongly-typed class (if possible) for reading the configuration from web.config or appsettings.json, since the projects that are using this class library are running framework 4.6.1 >= or dotnet core 2.0 >=.

I have tried this implementation:

```
public class TestConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
   [ConfigurationProperty("Types")]
   public ConfigurationCollection<TestItem> Types => 
      (ConfigurationCollection<TestItem>)this[nameof(Types)];
}

public class TestItem : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get => (string)this["Name"];

        set => this["Name"] = value;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Cluster_Name", DefaultValue = "Cluster123", IsRequired = false)]
    public string CouchbaseCluster
    {
        get => this["Cluster_Name"].ToString();
        set => this["Cluster_Name"] = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ConfigurationElement))]
public class ConfigurationCollection<T> : ConfigurationElementCollection where T : ConfigurationElement, new()
{
    public T this[int idx] => (T)BaseGet(idx);

    public new T this[string key] => (T)BaseGet(key);

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() => new T();

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element) => element.ToString();
}
```

With a web.config, which is .xml based, it can bind this strongly-typed class in a .net framework project but in a project running dotnet core with appsettings.json it doesn't bind:

```
"TestConfig": {
    "Types": [
      {
        "Name": "Default",
        "Cluster_Name": "DefaultCluster"
      },
      {
        "Name": "SomeRandomName1",
        "Cluster_Name": "TestCluster"
      }
    ]
}
```

Running this code in Startup.cs in a net5.0 project, value will be null:

```
var testConfig = Configuration.GetSection("TestConfig").Get<TestConfig>();
```

Comment: I don't think issue is in the config file.  All the config file does is set values of parameters.  For some reason the parameters are not being read correctly.  Try reading values in c# code to find root cause.  What do you get if you try following : var testConfig = Configuration.GetSection("TestConfig")

Comment: I have already tried that and `testConfig.value` i still equal to `null` so there is no difference.

Comment: See following for example of configuration array : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-of-environment-variables

Comment: You don't think that the issue is the config file? I've updated the names to be exactly the same with starting capital letter. Type TestConfig is working in framework projects but not in dotnet 5. Guessing is not what I was looking for. It's clearly comes down to the config file. If I just test with a type lets say TestConfig2 with standard properties with getters and setters without any attributes it works.

Comment: Originally on Mar 22 I did not think it was a config file.  When I posted the link on Mar 26 I realized by reading the link the issue could be the config file.  The link covers an number of different topics and did not know enough about your app to give a particular solution.